# Retrieve all ids

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How do you get all of the ids across the pages with `loadonce:true` and `datatype:json` in a jqGrid?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`data`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) option to retrieve the grid data directly:

```
 myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
```

Then you would need to iterate over `data` to retrieve each of your ID's.

Answer (score 2):

You need get `_index` parameter of jqGrid. It's object having ids as properties. If you need to have an array of ids (like with `getDataIDs` method) you can do the following

```
var id, ids = [], indexes = $("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "_index");
for (id in indexes) {
    if (indexes.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        ids.push(id);
    }
}
```

The code fills the `ids` array with the ids of the local grid.

By the way the value of the `_index` object (like `indexes[id]` in the for loop above) contains the index of the corresponding data object in the `$("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data")` array.

For example if you will fill the grid with the data like

```
var myData = [
        {id: "x", name: "abc", age: "12"},
        {id: "y", name: "def", age: "34"}
    ];
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    data: myData,
    datatype: "local",
    colModel: [{name: "name"}, {name: "age"}]
});
```

then the `$("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "_index")` will be object

```
{
    x: 0, // index of the data for the item having id="x"
    y: 1  // index of the data for the item having id="y"
}
```

and `$("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data")` will be array

```
[
    {name: "abc", age: "12"}
    {name: "def", age: "34"}
]
```